# AJAX-чат. Подскажите по поводу чата.

Tags: ajax, php

Как часто обращаться на сервер за новыми сообщениями?

И можно ли это сделать без обращений? Скажем посадить клинета на сокет. Или какие-то push-технологии.

Comment: Остановился на этом: http://spectrox.ru/blog/comet-theory-beginning/

Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем именно Node.JS? Есть много реализаций Comet серверов.

- [Dklab Realplexor](http://dklab.ru/lib/dklab_realplexor/) c PHP API от Дмитрия Котерова
- [NGiNX HTTP Push Module](http://pushmodule.slact.net/) достаточно просто использовать на любом backend'е.
- Да и свою реализацию на PHP не сложно реализовать. [Пример](http://spectrox.ru/blog/comet-theory-beginning/).

Comment: nodejs + сокеты всеравно, ИМХО - **лучше**

Comment: > ИМХО - лучше

Это аргумент :)

Answer (score 1):

Может быть посмотреть не в сторону Comet-сервера, а использовать более передовую технологию [WebSocket](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)?

Реализация на PHP есть, см.: [PHP5 WebSocket Chat](http://bohuco.net/blog/2011/01/php5-websocket-example-a-simple-chat/)

Comment: И в этом направлении как раз сейчас изучаю...

Только беда, что не все браузеры поддерживают...

Answer (score 0):

```
Node.JS
```

копай сюда

Comment: я думал....но ее на сервер надо ставить а я не умею и некому. и потом времени много уйдет на изучение....

Comment: Ну, тогда шли постоянные запросы серваку. Был вопрос, и получен ответ, а как ты будешь делать в итоге тут решай сам.

Comment: Ну да... глупый вопрос получился))) Все же без node.js никак нельзя посадить на сокет?

Comment: websockets, не канает?

Comment: Вариантов много. Выбирай какой тебе проще.

Comment: WebSocket - вещь! Попробую на нем.

Comment: > WebSocket - вещь! Попробую на нем.

Только имейте ввиду, что:

[WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)

> For the client side, WebSocket was implemented in Firefox 4, Google Chrome 4, Opera 11, and Safari 5, as well as the mobile version of Safari in iOS 4.2.

Так что, про IE можете забыть.

Comment: на ie > 9 робит и в опере новой. а на более старые версии подойдут и грязные хаки ввиде флеш прослойки или long polling.

Comment: времени много уйдет на изучение...

Интересно - это на что? на команду вывода и пару функций?

Comment: > а на более старые версии подойдут и грязные хаки ввиде флеш прослойки или long polling.

Да, конечно, так работать будет.

Но нужно помнить, что любые хаки могут вылиться в головную боль при разработке.

Comment: @AlexWindHope не не буду же я тупо писать код не разобравщись. И потом JS мне всегда трудно давался. NODE.JS мощная штука, но мне для простого онлайн помощника и обычный AJAX сгодиться.

Comment: Я вот про то и намекаю что @Ёхарный Бабай тебе будет проще именно просто с AJAX все решить.

Comment: по поводу проще я не согласен, например простой консольный чат на nodejs пишется в 25 строчек.

Comment: > не не буду же я тупо писать код не разобравщись.

Вооот оно, отличие прогера от приколов всяких))

Comment: 2 @Sh4dow чувствую подвох. и намек на то что "ни один прогер никогда не юзает чужого и не тестит у себя натыкаясь на грабли"

:) хехех